# Due Transaction propagation unable autowired component

Tags: java, spring, transactions, entitymanager

I started writing followed code using TDD:

```
 @Component("GrantingOfLoanSagaManager")
 public class GrantingOfLoanSagaManager implements
    SagaManager {

     private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     public GrantingOfLoanData createNewSagaData(AggregateId id ) {
         GrantingOfLoanData sagaData = new GrantingOfLoanData();
         sagaData.setRequestId(id);
         entityManager.persist(sagaData);
         return sagaData;
    }
 }
```

and test to this SagaManager class:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @WebAppConfiguration
 @ContextConfiguration(
    classes = ConfigTest.class)
 public class SagaTest {

     @PersistenceContext
     EntityManager entityManager;

     private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

     private GrantingOfLoanSagaManager sagaManager;

     @Autowired
     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
         this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
     }

     @Autowired
     public void setSagaManager(GrantingOfLoanSagaManager sagaManager) {
         this.sagaManager = sagaManager;
     }

     @Test
     @Transactional
     public void onCompleteEventsTriggered(){

     Client client = new Client();
         entityManager.persist(client);

     invokeFromSagaManagerCreateNewSagaData_method(); //some code that invoke via spring createNewSagaData() method in SagaManager
     }
}
```

But then I had some problems with this createNewSagaData() method because it use EntityManager to persist object in DB and naturally it should be run from Transactional context to save newSagaData in DB, co each method that call createNewSagaData() should have @Transactional annotation and create new transaction. So I found it to be incompatible solution, and I changed createNewSagaData method as follow:

```
    @Transactional //Annotation was added
    public GrantingOfLoanData createNewSagaData(AggregateId id ) {
        GrantingOfLoanData sagaData = new GrantingOfLoanData();
        sagaData.setRequestId(id);
        entityManager.persist(sagaData);
        return sagaData;
    }
```

As I mentioned I thought that the only thing I need is to create a new transaction (maybe with propagation=REQUIRED_NEW )

But after that when I run unitTests (/Integration test) I got follow exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.finance.app.core.domain.businessprocess.loangrant.GrantingOfLoanSagaManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So I don't know how to fix it. Should I use @Transactional to each outer method that call EntityManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bean names have to start with small letters if you use them as qualifiers like this: `@Component("grantingOfLoanSagaManager")`, but I wouldn't use qualifiers if there is no need for that. Autowire scans the proper bean by type. Also you should mark your whole test class with `@Transactional` and `@TransactionConfiguration`

Comment: I added TransactionConfiguration and Transactional annotation to test but it still faild with autowired GrantingOfLoanSagaManager

Comment: Did you remove the qualifier from your component. Also why are you autowiring an implementation class instead of an interface? In your test class you probably should do the wiring like `@Autowired private SagaManager sagaManager;`. Autowiring by constructor in test classes is not very clean to read either. Use it on fields.